# sql connection is making exception in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have this code

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestStoredProcedure"].ConnectionString);
```

This is my web.config

```
<add name="=TestStoredProcedure" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial     Catalog=testSqlServer;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

I got this exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on the connection string line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're referencing `ConnectionString` on something that doesn't exist:

```
ConnectionStrings["TestStoredProcedure"].ConnectionString
```

Your config file has `=TestStoredProcedure` as the name. That doesn't match your code. Remove the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Include following namespace line in your header of the page.

**using System.Configuration;**

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestStoredProcedure"].ConnectionString);
```

Web.Confiq:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestStoredProcedure" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial     Catalog=testSqlServer;Integrated Security=True"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Also remove **'='** from the name of the connection string.